# Elevating to High Integrity Level While Running as Administrator

Tags: c#, .net, permissions, windows-10

I have a C# WPF application which will conditionally evaluate its running integrity level and, if it's not high enough for the task at hand, will relaunch itself using the `runas` verb. In almost all cases, this approach works great -- if it decides that it needs to be elevated and has an integrity level < 0x3000 (High), then it relaunches with `runas` and everything is fine.

The problem with this approach is that it ironically doesn't work when a) the user running the application is the actual named "Administrator" account and b) the executable is labeled with a non-High integrity level (this can happen if you download an executable using a browser like Internet Explorer which applies the mandatory trust label on files it downloads).

It seems as though the `runas` verb is ignored when you're actually running as Administrator, but the trust labels are still evaluated. This results in the relaunched process retaining the same integrity level. Is there a way around this? I have no problem at all with the consent popup, but that simply doesn't (apparently: won't) occur while running as administrator. However, the IL limitations are still enforced if they're present on the (typically downloaded in most of our cases) executable.

*Note: Any solution I come up with has to allow the application to decide at runtime whether it requires elevation and opt into it if it's needed. There are circumstances where the app doesn't need additional privileges and thus shouldn't request elevation (thus using a manifest is sorta out as an option).*

Comment: The default system policy excepts the Administrator account (RID 500) from UAC, so it's at high integrity but it also uses the default [token mandatory policy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb394728), which includes `TOKEN_MANDATORY_POLICY_NEW_PROCESS_MIN`. This policy forces a child process to use the minimum integrity of the parent and executable file. When you elevate via the Appinfo service, this new-process-min policy is not enabled in the token. Since the Administrator account is and should be normally disabled, this is normally not a problem.

Comment: I can get around this, but it's not pretty. I start by opening the session's csrss.exe process (i.e. `CsrGetProcessId()`)  with limited-query access. Then open its token to impersonate the privileged SYSTEM user. Then duplicate the Administrator token as a new primary token and modify its mandatory policy to remove the new-process-min rule. Finally, revert to self and call `CreateProcessAsUser` with this modified token.

Comment: Hooboy. That does not sound pretty at all. I think I get the idea, though. I'll see if I can muddle my way through an implementation of that. This is quite a bit more knees-deep than I've gotten in the past, so wish me luck. Thank you for the pointers! Very much appreciated.

Comment: And yeah - I definitely hear you with regard to RID 500 Administrator usually being disabled. I've had users (engineers - the worst users) run into this enough times that I'm going to have to do something about it, unfortunately.

Comment: I forgot to mention that opening csrss.exe for limited-query access requires enabling SeDebugPrivilege.

Comment: Also, I'm not a .NET expert, but I can try to help if you're having difficulty with any of the WinAPI steps or concepts. You can edit your question and/or comment to try to refine and move forward to a solution and ultimately answer your own question.

Comment: Thanks @eryksun! That's extremely kind of you to offer and I am definitely going to take you up on it. I'm not familiar with the WinAPI bits, but I am becoming so. There are a lot of good examples of consuming the WinAPI via C# floating around for me to learn from. What I've done so far is attempt to acquire the `SeDebugPrivilege` (via `AdjustTokenPrivileges()`) and I'm encountering an Access Denied Win32 exception when trying to do that. Is it possible that the Medium integrity level would prevent that even if I'm otherwise fully elevated? If so, it seems like this approach might not work.

Comment: That's weird. Apparently I wasn't diligent enough in testing this. I checked in Process Explorer that the low/medium integrity process had the full privilege set, including SeDebugPrivilege. So I assumed this would work, but I actually tested from a high-integrity Administrator logon. Apparently the low/medium integrity token has a useless SeDebugPrivilege that cannot be enabled. Sorry for getting your hopes up.

Comment: Though the problem I'm getting isn't `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. Weirdly, it returns the disabled SeDebugPrivilege in `PreviousState` *as if* it were changed, but the last error is `ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED`, and SeDebugPrivilege remains in the disabled state.

Comment: Oh - that's really funny. I actually handled that scenario in my test code and treated it as if ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED was actually an error. If you retrieve the last error, it is an access denied error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some awesome help from @eryksun, it appears that you cannot do what I am trying to do. Once a process is launched under a Medium integrity level, it cannot escape this fate unless UAC is enabled. Since the RID 500 Administrator account is explicitly excluded from UAC, it's not possible while running as that user.

The best I can figure to do is detect this scenario by testing for the presence of the `TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE.TokenElevationTypeFull` in the process token information together with a process integrity level of < 0x3000. If you're stuck in that "you're elevated, but at a medium integrity level" jail, it doesn't appear there's a way out.

The user can avoid this fate by doing one of the following things:

- Not downloading the executable via a means that results in an IL label being applied to the file (e.g. not via Internet Explorer - probably some other browsers, also, but not Chrome by the look of it)
- Actively removing the IL label prior to execution (using `icacls`, for instance)
- Running the executable as a user other than the RID 500 Administrator (assuming the executable is otherwise already configured to relaunch itself with the `runas` verb if it requires elevation)